# Default user permissions

Tags: permissions, groups

I've made an error changing my default user permissions using `usermod -G groupName userName` (without -a). *My bad*.

So I went though a nasty process to recover `sudo` and `adm` permissions but I'm unsure which other permissions my default user should have. If you could confirm and explain their privilege it'll be very appreciated.

Thank you